# UIView combined animations with different durations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I would  like to animate an alpha change and a frame change on my view. Catch is I want the alpha change to end before the change of frame.
Currently I am doing something like this to achieve both simultaneously:

```
UIView *someview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
        [self.view addSubview:someview];
        someview.alpha = 0.0f;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100);
        }];
```

Comment: You can do this by using two different animations with different durations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100);
}];
```

to:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
}];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.4 animations:^{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform any changes after animation you should animateWithDuration with completion handler

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100);
    }];
```

**Replace above code with code give below**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100);
    }];
}];
```

In this block first alpha animation occurs, when completes frame animation will took place